# jboss.deployment.unit."testit-base.war".PARSE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "testit-base.war"

Tags: wildfly, jboss6.x, wildfly-18

We are planning to migrate the application from Jboss EAP 6.4 to WILDFLY 19 and facing the below error while deploying the war file in it.

```
    Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Built-By: jenkins
    Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
    Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_151
```

Platform : Wildfly 19

JDK version using in the server

```
    openjdk version "1.8.0_282"
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_282-b08)
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.282-b08, mixed mode)
```

Will this cause the compatibility issue ? Same war is deployed in JBOSS EAP 6.4 with JDK 1.8.0_151 installed in server . Could some one help me to understand the issue .Thanks in advance

```
    2021-03-03 19:00:58,126 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYPAT0050: WildFly Full cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
    2021-03-03 19:00:58,180 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "testit-base.war" (runtime-name: "testit-base.war")
    2021-03-03 19:00:58,184 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "externalapi.war" (runtime-name: "externalapi.war")
    2021-03-03 19:00:58,185 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "wmq.jmsra.rar" (runtime-name: "wmq.jmsra.rar")
    2021-03-03 19:00:58,234 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /opt/wildfly/server/deployments
    2021-03-03 19:00:59,051 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
    2021-03-03 19:00:59,253 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
    2021-03-03 19:00:59,875 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.4.1.Final (Apache CXF 3.3.5)
    2021-03-03 19:01:00,359 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
    2021-03-03 19:01:01,132 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry connector.jar in /content/wmq.jmsra.rar/com.ibm.mq.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
    2021-03-03 19:01:01,180 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jta.jar in /content/wmq.jmsra.rar/com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
    2021-03-03 19:01:01,183 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry ldap.jar in /content/wmq.jmsra.rar/com.ibm.mqjms.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
    2021-03-03 19:01:01,184 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jndi.jar in /content/wmq.jmsra.rar/com.ibm.mqjms.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
    2021-03-03 19:01:01,184 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry fscontext.jar in /content/wmq.jmsra.rar/com.ibm.mqjms.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
    2021-03-03 19:01:01,184 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry providerutil.jar in /content/wmq.jmsra.rar/com.ibm.mqjms.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
    2021-03-03 19:01:01,203 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jms.jar in /content/wmq.jmsra.rar/com.ibm.msg.client.jms.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
    2021-03-03 19:01:01,206 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry rmm.jar in /content/wmq.jmsra.rar/com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
    2021-03-03 19:01:01,207 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry CL3Export.jar in /content/wmq.jmsra.rar/com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
    2021-03-03 19:01:01,207 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry CL3Nonexport.jar in /content/wmq.jmsra.rar/com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
    2021-03-03 19:01:04,020 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RADeployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) IJ020001: Required license terms for file:/opt/wildfly/server/tmp/vfs/temp/temp9866aa9ab5895a5a/content-7c3c685b4673a9c7/contents/
    2021-03-03 19:01:04,953 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment externalapi.war
    2021-03-03 19:01:05,350 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-1) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Infinity Minus ONE +2' 9.4.18.Final
    2021-03-03 19:01:05,628 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-2) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.18.Final
    2021-03-03 19:01:05,859 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry lib/snakeyaml-1.13.jar in /content/testit-base.war/WEB-INF/lib/liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
    2021-03-03 19:01:05,862 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry xercesImpl.jar in /content/testit-base.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.0.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
    2021-03-03 19:01:05,862 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in /content/testit-base.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.0.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
    2021-03-03 19:01:05,863 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry serializer.jar in /content/testit-base.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.0.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
    2021-03-03 19:01:06,129 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3) Could not initialize log file, java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: mqjms.log.0.lck
    2021-03-03 19:01:06,165 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3) March 3, 2021 7:01:06 PM CET[MSC service thread 1-3] ResourceAdapterImpl
    2021-03-03 19:01:06,165 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3) WMQ messaging : '7.5.0.6-p750-006-160226'.
    2021-03-03 19:01:06,165 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)
    2021-03-03 19:01:06,165 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3) EXPLANATION:
    2021-03-03 19:01:06,165 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3) null
    2021-03-03 19:01:06,165 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)
    2021-03-03 19:01:06,166 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3) ACTION:
    2021-03-03 19:01:06,166 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3) null
    2021-03-03 19:01:06,166 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3) --------------------------------------------------------------------
    2021-03-03 19:01:06,433 WARN  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RADeployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) IJ020017: Invalid archive: file:/opt/wildfly/server/tmp/vfs/temp/temp9866aa9ab5895a5a/content-7c3c685b4673a9c7/contents/
    2021-03-03 19:01:06,499 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."testit-base.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."testit-base.war".PARSE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "testit-base.war"
            at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:183)
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
            at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
            at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
            at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
            at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.getRequiredService(ServiceContainerImpl.java:663)
            at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.getDefaultResourceAdapterName(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:248)
            at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.processMessageBeans(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:156)
            at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.processAnnotations(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:83)
            at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.processAnnotations(AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:50)
            at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.deploy(AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:76)
            at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:176)
            ... 8 more
    
    2021-03-03 19:01:07,346 WARN  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYRS0018: Explicit usage of Jackson annotation in a JAX-RS deployment; the system will disable JSON-B processing for the current deployment. Consider setting the 'resteasy.preferJacksonOverJsonB' property to 'false' to restore JSON-B.
    2021-03-03 19:01:07,455 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-4) WELD-000900: 3.1.3 (Final)
    2021-03-03 19:01:07,762 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
    2021-03-03 19:01:09,806 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class ExternalApiApplication
    2021-03-03 19:01:09,808 WARN  [org.jboss.as.weld] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) WFLYWELD0052: Using deployment classloader to load proxy classes for module com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider. Package-private access will not work. To fix this the module should declare dependencies on [org.jboss.weld.core, org.jboss.weld.spi, org.jboss.weld.api]
    2021-03-03 19:01:09,966 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/externalapi' for server 'default-server'
    2021-03-03 19:01:09,978 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "testit-base.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"testit-base.war\".PARSE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"testit-base.war\"
        Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found"}}
    2021-03-03 19:01:09,996 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "wmq.jmsra.rar" (runtime-name : "wmq.jmsra.rar")
    2021-03-03 19:01:09,996 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "externalapi.war" (runtime-name : "externalapi.war")
    2021-03-03 19:01:09,996 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "testit-base.war" (runtime-name : "testit-base.war")
    2021-03-03 19:01:09,998 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
    WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."testit-base.war".PARSE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "testit-base.war"
    
    2021-03-03 19:01:10,146 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
    2021-03-03 19:01:10,149 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
    2021-03-03 19:01:10,149 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
    2021-03-03 19:01:10,149 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 19.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 11.0.0.Final) started (with errors) in 28607ms - Started 487 of 679 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 338 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Resource adapters settings are as below,

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:5.0">
        <resource-adapters>
            <resource-adapter id="wmq.jmsra.rar">
                <archive>
                    wmq.jmsra.rar
                </archive>
                <transaction-support>NoTransaction</transaction-support>
                <connection-definitions>
                    <connection-definition class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl" jndi-name="java:jboss/WMQConnectionFactory" pool-name="WMQConnectionFactory">
                        <config-property name="channel">
                            CL.SC1023AC.TIMS
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="hostName">
                            sc1023ac.domain.com
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="transportType">
                            Client
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="queueManager">
                            SC1023AC
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="port">
                            49400
                        </config-property>
                    </connection-definition>
                </connection-definitions>
                <admin-objects>
                    <admin-object class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy" jndi-name="java:jboss/queue/PurchaseOrderExportQueue" pool-name="purchaseOrderExport">
                        <config-property name="baseQueueName">
                            RQ.SCCO4234
                        </config-property>
                    </admin-object>>
                </admin-objects>
            </resource-adapter>
        </resource-adapters>
    </subsystem>


    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:6.0">
        <session-bean>
            <stateless>
                <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>
            </stateless>
            <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="distributable" passivation-disabled-cache-ref="simple"/>
            <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
        </session-bean>
        <mdb>
            <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="${ejb.resource-adapter-name:wmq.jmsra.rar}"/>
            <!--resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="wmq.jmsra.rar"/-->
            <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
        </mdb>
```

Answer (score 0):

You WMQ resource adapter is not working properly as stated in:

```
2021-03-03 19:01:06,129 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3) Could not initialize log file, java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: mqjms.log.0.lck
2021-03-03 19:01:06,165 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3) March 3, 2021 7:01:06 PM CET[MSC service thread 1-3] ResourceAdapterImpl
2021-03-03 19:01:06,165 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3) WMQ messaging : '7.5.0.6-p750-006-160226'.
2021-03-03 19:01:06,165 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)
2021-03-03 19:01:06,165 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3) EXPLANATION:
2021-03-03 19:01:06,165 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3) null
2021-03-03 19:01:06,165 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)
2021-03-03 19:01:06,166 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3) ACTION:
2021-03-03 19:01:06,166 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3) null
2021-03-03 19:01:06,166 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3) --------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-03-03 19:01:06,433 WARN  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RADeployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) IJ020017: Invalid archive: file:/opt/wildfly/server/tmp/vfs/temp/temp9866aa9ab5895a5a/content-7c3c685b4673a9c7/contents/
```

This makes the ejbs fail

Comment: Thank you , i've tried deploying the another WMQ resource adapter but still it failed .Same adapter is working fine in JBOSS 6.4 . 
Do we have to change any configurations in standalone-full.xml for wildfly 19 ?

Comment: I think that IBM resource adapter tries to write some log file somewhere where it can't (AccessDenied). Maybe you should configure that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to deploy your own JMS service rather than use Artemis, but that something is still trying to use the default, which presumably isn't there as I assume you are using the standalone not standalone-full profile

Comment: I am using standalone-full-ha.xml ,

Comment: WMQ resource adapter settings looks like above , is there anything to change in it?